# data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt; No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, google-colaboratory

Please Help me!
Thanks in Advance 
i am creating a object detector using python in google colab .

please tell me what to do?
Is there any module version error or a file directory missing ?
if the directory is missing so tell me how can i add.
Please help me as fast as you can.
once again thank you so much .

When i run this code it gives this error

````
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)```.


**This is the output**

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py:132: The name tf.gfile.GFile is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.GFile instead.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b47b5c1dba35> in <module>()
      1 import os
----> 2 label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
      3 categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
      4 category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py in _preread_check(self)
     82                                            "File isn't open for reading")
     83       self._read_buf = pywrap_tensorflow.CreateBufferedInputStream(
---> 84           compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
     85 
     86   def _prewrite_check(self):

NotFoundError: data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt; No such file or directory
````

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) (tl;dr: **never**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you defined as **`PATH_TO_LABELS`**?

It should point to your **`pbtxt`**  file (preferably the full path - i.e. starts with **`/content`** in a Colab.

Comment: PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

Comment: Please tell me how can i do that

Comment: Change to: --> **`PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('/content', 'data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')`** --- This assumes that the **`data`** folder is in the folder tree where you see it on the left. If this is not the case than find the **`data`** folder in the file tree on the left of the colab, right click it and click **`copy path`**. Paste this somewhere so you can see the whole path. Then just make the appropriate **`os.path.join`** command accordingly.

Comment: In the actual github repo for the Object Detection API this is the path from the repo root. **`models/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt`** hopefully this may help.

Comment: **I got another error can you please answer this** `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'` in my numpy module do you know the correct version of numpy for this object detection project or how can i fix this

Comment: please Review this question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238210/i-got-an-error-in-my-object-detection-project-its-a-type-error-numpy

Comment: From this https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/requirements.txt -- you can see that the numpy>=1.15.4 is required. I'll stop here and move on to your other question and try to help there.

Answer (score 0):

First, click the files button on the left-hand side to find the dataset and ensure you have indeed downloaded it. Often the paths in colab are a bit different from the ones we use. So after locating the dataset, right-click on the file and get it's correct path to use in the code.

If even then the import doesn't work then probably you need to restart the runtime due to unforeseen glitches that commonly arrive in colab. If the error persists upload the dataset to Google Drive and mount it to your runtime. It solves a lot of file-based issues....